# Как заменить последовательность заданных в разном порядке спец символов одним пробелом?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, kotlin

У меня есть набор символов, который не должен содержаться в строке. Кроме того, количество подряд идущих произвольных символов неизвестно. Мне необходимо найти в строке каждую подстроку со спецсимволами и заменить ее на пробел.

Вот мой вариант:

```java
string.replace("[\n\r\t\u000B\u000C]*".toRegex(), " ");
```

Проблема в том, что он подставляет пробел после каждого символа почему-то. Где я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Символы в квадратных скобках `[ ]` - это *символьный класс*. Он подразумевает вхождение в искомую комбинацию любого из перечисленных символов.

`[ ]*` - количество символов `0` и более;

`[ ]+` - количество символов `1` и более;

`[ ]` - только один символ из перечисленных.

В данном случае приоритетный вариант - `[ ]+`, иначе при замене будет много пробелов.

См. [Регулярные выражения (regular expressions)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

---

**UPD:** для замены всех вхождений различных последовательностей пробельных символов на один пробел можно использовать:

```java
string.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

См. [Можно ли как-то изменять много символов в одном replace()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1148923/328896)