# Можно ли как-то изменять много символов в одном replace()

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, replace

Можно ли как-то изменять много символов в одном `replace()`?

Например, если я хочу заменить ещё и `*` на `;`.

```
String str1 = str.replace("#", ";");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте RegEx

```
str = str.replaceAll("[0-9]", ";");
```

Ну или вашем случае

```
str = str.replaceAll("[*#]", ";");
```

Comment: это же заменяет все цифры от 0 до 9? мне бы нужно заменить два символа на один

Comment: @LoveOnlyPython ну так используйте `replaceAll("[#*]", ";")`

Comment: Я вообще-то показал идею. Думал заменить цыфры на нужные символы не составит труда

Comment: @LoveOnlyPython, `str = str.ReplaceAll("[*#]+", ";");` это должно заменить последовательность символом на один

Answer (score 2):

Метод [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) заменяет все вхождения в текущей строке *литерала* (т.е. последовательности символов) на другой *литерал*.

Метод [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) заменяет все вхождения в текущей строке *литералов*, соответствующих переданному [регулярному выражению](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), на другой *литерал*.

---

В вашем случае лучше использовать `replaceAll`:

```java
String str1 = str.replaceAll("[*#]", ";");
```

Либо можно использовать цепочку `replace`:

```java
String str1 = str.replace("#", ";").replace("*", ";");
```

---

**UPD:** Есть ещё старый метод [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)), кототый заменяет все вхождения в текущей строке определенного символа `char` на другой символ `char`:

```java
String str1 = str.replace('#', ';').replace('*', ';');
```